# Magento 2 - Page Speed Insights / Lighthouse Audits Low Scores

Tags: magento2, performance, pagespeed

I noticed recently the Google page speed insights has improved somewhat, shows a lot more information however is harsh especially it seems for Magento 2 (I can get 98 so far from other non Magento 2 websites).

I am used to being able to getting Page Speed insights scores into the 80s and 90s with some light tweaks although felt this was just ticking check boxes (deferring resource, using optimised images, gzip and caching resources, avoiding redirects etc) and now it seems a bit more real based on performance of the site. Now however I am looking at scores of 30 ish.

I'm concerned as although testing my sites do not feel overly slow I have always thought Magento 2 seems a bit weighty especially on the JavaScript side with a lot going on client side on page load slowing the "time to interactive" that shows with 3G mobile audit to around 15 seconds.

I have recently took a few steps to improve including no longer merging JavaScript as this seems to make my page size considerable larger i think about 5MB down to 2MB was what I witnessed. Deferring loading of images. Further improvements I want to move to is the Varnish cache although im not sure it would help these scores particularly here as my TTFB is reasonably quick with built in FPC. I want to try HTTP2 especially since dropping merging of JS there are a lot of separate resources this may help. Using WEBP for example instead of JPEG etc for catalog images.

I'm posting this question as want to know if everyone else is as bad and what measures you have taken to improve these poor scores?

I guess at the end of the day it is all relative and everyone will get worse scores I'm just slightly concerned Magento may be hit harder than other eCommerce platforms and not sure on the SEO side of this but would like to atleast try and improve as this cannot be good... Further tests on competitor sites shows some sites still in the 60-70 range this seem to be on much lighter eCommerce platforms.

Comment: I am bouncing to the same thing at the moment. I guess it is about user experience vs google ranking now. I can get the speed score above 40 even with varnish